# How to Display Corners of Big Matrices with Fancy Ellipsis Characters

Tags: grid-layouts, display

Say I have a big matrix

```
testMat = Partition[Range[16*2048], 2048];
```

and I want to display a block in the upper left corner, say defaulting to a 4-by-4 block, plus the last column and last row, with ellipsis characters to fill in the missing bits:

[image]

Now, I have a trog solution (brute-force, stupid, ugly, brittle, code-smelly), shown below. My question is how to improve the many defects of this solution, the worst of which is:

It fails utterly if the row count or column count of the requested block is near the full size of the matrix; it always assumes the full matrix contains at least two rows more and two columns more than the requested block.

Perhaps its only saving grace is that it is very earthy, concrete, explicit, and simple-minded enough to be self-explanatory.

Here is my trog for your destruction, dissection, and reassembly into a beautiful unicorn:

```
ClearAll[appendColumn, appendRow];
appendColumn[m_, 
   c_] := ((m\[Transpose])~Join~(c\[Transpose]))\[Transpose];
appendRow[m_, r_] := Append[m, r[[1]]];

testMat = Partition[Range[16*2048], 2048];

ClearAll[sliceULCornerAndLastsG, showAsSBG, gridG];
With[{last = -1, ac = appendColumn, ar = appendRow, 
   vdots = \[VerticalEllipsis], ddots = \[DescendingEllipsis] , 
   dots = \[CenterEllipsis]},
  With[{llast = Span[last, last]},
   showAsSBG[label_, lastRowIndex_, lastColIndex_, m_, rows_ : 4, cols_ : 4] :=

    Module[{c = 
       ar[ar[List /@ 
          Table["row " <> ToString[i], {i, 0, 
            rows - 1}], {{vdots}}], {{"row " <> 
           ToString[lastRowIndex - 1]}}],
      r1 = {Flatten@{label, ConstantArray["col", cols], dots, 
          "col"}},
      r2 = {Flatten@{"", Table[i, {i, 0, cols - 1}], dots, LastColIndex - 1}}},
     Join[r1, r2, ac[c, m]]];
   sliceULCornerAndLastsG[m_, rows_ : 4, cols_ : 4] :=
    Module[{
      ul = m[[;; rows, ;; cols]],
      lastColU = m[[;; rows, llast]],
      lastRowL = m[[llast, ;; cols]],
      lastLast = m[[llast, llast]],
      oneDots = {{vdots}},
      lRowDots = {ConstantArray[vdots, cols]},
      colDots = List /@ ConstantArray[dots, rows + 2]},
     colDots[[-2, 1]] = ddots;
     ac[ac[ar[ar[ul, lRowDots], lastRowL], colDots],
      ar[ar[lastColU, oneDots], lastLast]]];
   gridG[label_, m_, rows_ : 4, cols_ : 4] :=

    showAsSBG[label, Length[m], Length[m[[1]]],
      sliceULCornerAndLastsG[testMat, rows, cols], rows, cols] //

      Grid[#,
       Frame -> {None, None,
         {{{3, rows + 4}, {2, cols + 3}} -> True,
          {{1, 2}, {1, 1}} -> True,
          {{3, rows + 4}, {1, 1}} -> True,
          {{1, 2}, {2, cols + 3}} -> True}}] &
   ]];
gridG["Foo", testMat]
gridG["Bar", testMat, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative rule-based solution:

```
hideRows[table_, {n_, m_}] := Replace[
  table,
  {first : Repeated[{__}, {n}], middle__, last_} :> {first, Join[ConstantArray[\[VerticalEllipsis], m], {\[DescendingEllipsis], \[VerticalEllipsis]}], last}
  ]
hideColumns[table_, {n_, m_}] := Replace[
  table,
  {first : Repeated[_, {m}], __, last_} :> {first, \[CenterEllipsis], last}, {1}
  ]
simplifyTable[table_, {n_ : 3, m_ : 6}] := hideRows[hideColumns[table, {n, m}], {n, m}]

rowHeadings[n_, nmax_] := With[
  {tmpl = StringTemplate["row ``"]},
  Join[tmpl /@ Range[n], {\[VerticalEllipsis], tmpl@nmax}]
  ]

colHeadings[n_, nmax_] := With[
  {tmpl = StringTemplate["col\n``"]},
  Join[tmpl /@ Range[n], {"\[CenterEllipsis]\n\[CenterEllipsis]", tmpl@nmax}]
  ]

showTable[table_, {n_ : 3, m_ : 6}] := Module[{nrows, ncols},
  {nrows, ncols} = Dimensions[table];
  TableForm[
   simplifyTable[table, {n, m}],
   TableHeadings -> {
     rowHeadings[n, nrows],
     colHeadings[m, ncols]
     }
   ]
  ]

showTable[testMat, {3, 6}]
```

[image: Example]